# How can I force iPad to always Request Desktop Site?

Tags: vb.net, ipad

At my new company I am maintaining a VB.Net webforms application. We are seeing an issue when viewing the site on an iPad that can be fixed by Requesting Desktop Site in either Chrome or Safari. 
Is there a way to force this in code so the user does not have to hold the refresh button in Safari and request the desktop site?

UPDATE:
We are using Telerik controls and the functionality changes when its displayed on an iPad vs a browser on a desktop. When I pull up the page on an iPad the textbox filters will not work until I select Request Desktop Site, see below for wrong incorrect version.

[image]

Here is what it looks like after that is selected and normally on a desktop browser. [image]

So I need a way to force the browser to request the desktop site/version when viewing on an iPad.

Comment: You should fix your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Without some examples its tricky to comment on this, but I think I know how to get the result you want. In the HTML of the page(s):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Source [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

This should fix the issue you're seeing in all browsers, if it is what I think it is.

Edit: Question has been significantly updated, this is definitely not the right answer.